# exchange server 2007 make 2 send connector

Tags: exchange-server-2007

I am new on the exchange server.

I have more than one e-mail on the exchange server and one send connector with the smtp with gmail.

I need to add another connector and connect some mails to send by this connector, so how can I do that in the exchange server 2007?

I already know how to add a new sender connector but how can I connect some e-mails with new send connector?

Answer (score 0):

Exchange alone can unfortunately NOT do that. You can have more than one send connector but Exchange can't choose a specific send connector based on the sender of the email. You need to use a 3rd party add-on to do this. Try MultiSendcon (http://www.servolutions.com/multisendcon.htm) - it's easy to configure and solves the problem.

Comment: can i find any one free